# How to pass a querystring with javascript and use it in codebehind page in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, query-string

Currently I am opening a page in dialog box as shown below using JavaScript. I am passing a query string by encrypting it to the list page .

```
function Popup() {

        if (document.getElementById("<%= Amount.ClientID %>").value != "") {
            var xorKey = 13;
            var Obj = window;
            var id = document.getElementById("<%= id.ClientID %>").value + "-" + document.getElementById("<%= Amount.ClientID %>").value;

            var result = "";
            for (i = 0; i < id.length; ++i) {
                param += String.fromCharCode(xorKey ^ id.charCodeAt(i));
            }

            window.showModalDialog("list.aspx?id=" + param, Obj, "dialogWidth:800px; dialogHeight:500px; dialogLeft:252px; dialogTop:120px; center:yes");
        }

    }
```

Now on code behind page I am using this code :

```
string id = Request.QueryString[0].ToString();
            StringBuilder inSb = new StringBuilder(id);
            StringBuilder outSb = new StringBuilder(id.Length);
            char c;
            for (int i = 0; i < id.Length; i++)
            {
                c = inSb[i];
                c = (char)(c ^ 13); /// remember to use the same XORkey value you used in javascript
                outSb.Append(c);
            }
            string[] idvalue = outSb.ToString().Split('-');
            id = idvalue[0].ToString();
```

Now when using the `Querystring[0]` I am only getting the pre decimal values like if the value I type in textbox is `13.33`, then I am on the list page getting only `13`. Can anybody help me?

Thank you.

Comment: What's the final URL formed after calling **Popup**?

Comment: @HaseebAsif : sorry my mistake its this one localhost:6651/random/Page/list.aspx?id= <>#>>

Comment: You need to URL encode your values. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use escape on the param variable as follows

```
window.showModalDialog("list.aspx?id=" + escape(param), Obj, "dialogWidth:800px; dialogHeight:500px; dialogLeft:252px; dialogTop:120px; center:yes");
```

or encodeURI

```
window.showModalDialog(encodeURI("list.aspx?id=" + param), Obj, "dialogWidth:800px; dialogHeight:500px; dialogLeft:252px; dialogTop:120px; center:yes");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use encodeURIComponent() to encode your url before sending it to the server.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp

Edit: Added link to source.